# Stacking Div On Top Of Other Header Elements

Tags: css, html

I'm having difficulty in placing a div containing contact info in my header. I've been reading up on this issue for a few hours & haven't quite found a solution yet. I'm trying to stack my contact info on the top right of my layout.

--

**Image of what I'd like to achieve:**

http://i45.tinypic.com/2zrgu8o.jpg

**Image of what my code is currently producing:**

http://i48.tinypic.com/mbhlcz.jpg

--

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css" />

    </head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" /></head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">

<div id="logo">
<img src="/images/logo-top.png">
</div>

<div class="contact">
Email: sadlkj@yahoo.com | Phone: 1 (732) 235-7239
</div>



<div id="header-bg"> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
#logo {
    postion: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;

} 

#header-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;       
    background-image: url("/images/header-bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: -1;


}

.contact {
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;}
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: your header will be fixed when scrolling?

Comment: Unfortunately, these suggestions haven't helped. I do appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `<span>` instead of a div, either that or using `<div style="display: inline;">`

Answer (score 0):

You've got it all right, you just have a typeo in your class definition. You have to say 0px rather than just 0 for your positioning

```
top:0px;
left:0px;
```

Here... take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/t5LZL/2/

Comment: as my fiddle shows, 0 doesn't work (at least not in Chrome or Firefox)

Comment: If I'm wrong (and the fiddle clearly shows I'm not) then it would be polite to explain what you take issue with in my answer rather than just downvoting without an explanation

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by putting the `contact` `div` BEFORE the `logo` `div` in your HTML.

`float`s only float to the right or the left, not up. The `contact` `div` is below the bottom of the `logo` `div` and so floats right at that level. By putting it before the `logo` it floats right before the `logo` pushes it down.

Answer (score 0):

use this html structure and change your css

```
<div id="header-bg"> 
<div class='center_wrap'> 
 <div id="logo">
 <img src="/images/logo-top.png">
 </div>

 <div class="contact">
 Email: sadlkj@yahoo.com | Phone: 1 (732) 235-7239
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

can't do more luck of time